# Best Data Structure for an Entity-Component-System Framework

Tags: frameworks, entity, game-engine

I've been reading a lot about Entity Frameworks and now I want to implement it on my game. An Entity Framework is based on making the game entities simple containers of Components, where a Component contains a certain characteristic of an Entity (and all the variables/accessors which describe this characteristic).
The game logic is then modularized by creating Systems. Each System implements and runs a certain aspect of the game logic (eg. Collisions, Rendering, Animation). Each System has to be able to access every Entity which has some certain combination of Components (eg. RenderSystem has to get **only** Entities which have PositionComponent and AnimationComponent).

My question regards the best data structure for achieving such functionality.

My current idea is to create a Vector (with N cells, where N is the number of possible components) of List of Entity. So whenever I create (instantiate and add certain Components) an Entity, I would also reference this Entity from each List for each Component it contains. "Killing" an Entity would require removing each reference from each List. The problem would be querying which entities have to be processed by a certain System, because the search-key would be a **combination** of Components, and not a single Component, adding overhead to the operation (many searches and comparisons would have to be done).

Is my idea good? Is there any better data structure I can use? Note that everything in the game is supposed to be an Entity, summing up to thousands of Entites on a single Level (I could possibly use some space partitioning).

Comment: I would use a [Visitor pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077602/learn-java/java-tip-98--reflect-on-the-visitor-design-pattern.html).

Comment: To achieve the best data structure? Genius!

Answer (score 0):

They are two ways of doing it,

The purely data oriented system would lead you not to have an Entity class but just components sharing an ID. In this case, a vector or a hashmap for every system wouldn't be a problem as the search in these data structure is fast. If you want several components per system per entity you can aggregate your components in one data structure adapted for each system.

The problem is that a pure data oriented system can be less usable than a more pragmatic approach where you keep all the features of the previously described system but you keep an entity class that holds reference to his components (or aggregated components structures) of every system. Processing an entity (deleting or inspecting it) becomes much easier as you still have a place where all the information about what the entity is, i.e. what it is made of and not what state it is in, can be found in one place instead of querying every system.

In your case, the best thing is to try... It's quite easy and fast to implement a rough engine in the two ways, and once you've played with the two you'll be able to decide which one suites you better.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2014/03/08/data-structures-for-entity-systems-contiguous-memory/) is valuable as far as it suggests 4 iterations for the data structure, but no one is a good solution in my opinion. But I recommend to read it, because there is a detailed analysis of the problem, nice estimations in terms of memory and such other good material.

Comment: Link is broken, is this the article http://t-machine.org/index.php/2014/03/08/data-structures-for-entity-systems-contiguous-memory/ ?